# Printing on galaxy S5

Tags: android, printing, webview

I have a printing feature in my app which works on devices I tested with. Unfortunately I got this feedback from users:

Problem with galaxy S5: pdf print doesn't work. Error is: "fail to change settings".

I am printing like this - afaik correctly:

```
 @TargetApi(19)
    private fun createWebPrintJob(webView: WebView) {
        val printManager = getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE) as PrintManager
        val jobName = getString(org.ligi.survivalmanual.R.string.app_name) + " Document"
        val printAdapter = WebViewCompat.createPrintDocumentAdapter(webView, jobName)
        printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter, PrintAttributes.Builder().build())
    }
```

Anyone else got this and perhaps a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Webview [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=664400). It should be fixed in the latest webview update.